# htaccess 301 for non friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect non friendly urls to X?
Found this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yourdomain.com/newpage.html
```

But this code only apply to friendly urls or specific files.

I need to do something like:

```
www.example.com/?option=com_content&view=article&id=66&Itemid=109
```

to

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect those URLs to a "pretty" URL, you will need rules like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \?option=.* ./index.php
```

If you want to apply it to non-existent URLs, use something like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /your_page.html
```

For more help, see and example like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049)